# WCF rest service client certificate issue

Tags: wcf, iis, ssl

I have a SSL secured (https) restful WCF service hosted in IIS (7.5). This service has 2 endpoints. One endpoint is expects a client certificate and other do not expect a client certificate.
Client certificate setting in IIS is

[image]

Now, when i run my test case from Visual studio, everything works fine. No problems.
Problem is when the actual client (which is a website hosted in IIS), tries to communicate with the WCF service over the endpoint which do NOT expect client certificate.
When the website make such call, the browser (IE, Chrome), pops up a dialog box to select the client certificate.
If the endpoint is not expecting client certificate then why the browser is popping up this dialog box to select a client certificate?

Endpoint bindings look like this

```html
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webBinding">
     <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
     </security>
    </binding>
        <binding name="webSecureBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
   </webHttpBinding>
```

Comment: can you paste how your certificate bindings/behavior looks like for WCF?

Comment: Are you listening at the same Endpoint Address for both bindings?

Comment: @Derek: No. Endpoint url are different.

Comment: So you are requesting at the Endpoint Address with the Non-Certificate equipped binding, yet you get a response which demands a client certificate for authorization?

Comment: Can you provide the code that is actually dealing with the assignment of Endpoint Addresses?